# Run-time error '1004' The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save my workbook every 10 minutes but I keep getting the run time error 1004. The code shown is in one of the modules. My program will save my entire workbook as today's date into a folder.

Everything was working perfectly fine until I ran the code and then saved it and now I get that error.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim path As String
Dim filename1 As String



path = "C:\Users\100020427\Desktop\FPYFiles\"

filename1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Totals").Range("M10").Text
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If ThisWorkbook.Name = filename1 Then
    ThisWorkbook.save
    MsgBox "Today's Form has been saved! Click Ok Button"
Else
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & filename1, FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False
    MsgBox "Today's Form has been saved! Click Ok Button"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'ActiveWorkbook.save Filename:=path & filename1, FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False
'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "CommandButton1_Click"
End Sub

Sub Workbook_Open()
CommandButton1_Click
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "CommandButton1_Click"
End Sub
```

I expect is to save workbook as the date in the listed location

[image]

Comment: What is the content of `M10`? Are you aware that you read cell `M10` of the current active sheet - which may be different all the time.

Comment: Yes the contents of M10 is the current date, it changes each day. But at the end of the day that file is saved as the current date obviously and then closed and then that same template will be used for next day.

Comment: What format is that date? You can't have `/` in filenames...

Comment: But is the sheet active in the moment you code executes? As you wait for 10min, it can be any sheet. Plus, check if the date contains any characters that are invalid as filename. Put a `Debug.Print filename1` statement in your code before the `SaveAs`statement

Comment: I am aware the date cant have / I use underscore such as 2019_6_11. Yes FunThomas it is active when it saves every 10 minutes

Comment: I did the debug.print filename1 before and now i get the run time '1004' application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: @ChadO'Bryan Could you please add a screenshot of your value in `Range("M10")`?

Comment: @dwirony yes just did link "M10"

Comment: @ChadO Can you try adding `.xlsm` to the end of `filename1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your setup correctly, you are issuing a `SaveAs`-command every 10 minutes, and the filename will contain the current date. So, the filename is the same during the whole day, and that will cause a failure when the `SaveAs` is issued a second time.

Why? You ask Excel to overwrite an existing file. As you suppress warnings, you will not see the message *"The file already exists, do you want to replace it?"*. Excel then tries to overwrite the last version of the file with the current one, but as the file is (obviously) open, this will fail.

Change your piece of code so that the `SaveAs` is only executed if you really write a new file. In all other cases, use `Save` rather than `SaveAs`. Note that I added the extension to the filename so that the check is successfull. I also fully qualified the cell where the filename is expected so that the code will not fail when a different sheet or workbook is currently active.

```
fileName1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("M10") & ".xlsm"

If ThisWorkbook.Name = fileName1 Then
    ThisWorkbook.Save
Else
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs path & fileName1, 52
End If
```

Comment: Your code would be clearer, if you wrote `path & filename1`, rather than `p & "fileName"`, cf. the OP's notation.

Comment: @Miqi180: You're right - my mistake when C&P from a quick test I did. Corrected

Comment: That happens :) Anyway, I still think it would be clearer if you passed the string variable `filename1` instead of a string in which he needs to replace `filename` with the actual file name. Btw, I think your solution is correct given his problem statement, but as he's probably a noob, I think your notation might have thrown him off a bit...

Comment: You're right. It was never meant to have a hardcoded string there (and it makes no sense anyhow), corrected it a second time... Time to go home.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help everyone, got it figured out, everything works!